# Calcular o percentual de hora PHP

Tags: php

Preciso calcular o percentual de cada hora de um `array`.
Por exemplo:

Hora1: 04:45 
Hora2: 01:30 
Hora3: 00:45 
Total: 07:00

```
$array = array('04:45','01:30','00:45');
```

Fiz o calculo no excel, e o resultado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT**

Segue o PHP que estou tentando, porem está retornando valores diferentes:

```
$array = array('04:45', '01:30', '00:45');
      foreach ($array as $tem => $key) {
      $total = '07:00';
      $tempo = $key;

      $percentual = round(($tempo / $total) * 100);

      $percentual_total .= "Tempo: " . $tempo . ", Percentual: " . $percentual . "<br>";
}

 echo $percentual_total;
```

Retorno do PHP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: percentual de que? ninguém advinha aqui, e se voce fez no excel, difere pouco de fazer em php ou outra linguagem qualquer, o processo eh praticamente igual.

Comment: De cada hora do array, você não viu no titulo da pergunta?

Comment: vi @Eduardo Santos, mas, veja, 67,857... e o percentual de 5 horas? 1 hora?, ficou meio sem base a sua questão, e foi como disse, do excel pro php eh um pulozinho de nada, se voce jah tem la, voce poderia nos dizer qual seria sua dificuldade em php?

Comment: Não que seja resposta para sua pergunta, mas acho que, se você quiser apenas o percentual, ficaria mais fácil converter tudo para minutos

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com o que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Deu pra entender o propósito. A pergunta que ficou mal formulada. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**resultado - ideone**](https://ideone.com/OYU3Ip)

Transformei  `$total` em minutos e no foreach a cada iteração, o valor do elemento `$key` também em minutos para efetuar os cálculos com as mesmas unidades.

```
$array = array('04:45', '01:30', '00:45');

$total = '07:00';
$explodeHoraTotal = explode(":",$total); //retorna um array onde cada elemento é separado por ":"
$minutosTotal = $explodeHoraTotal[0];
$minutosTotal = $minutosTotal*60;
$total =$minutosTotal+$explodeHoraTotal[1];

foreach ($array as $tem => $key) {

      $quebraHora = explode(":",$key); //retorna um array onde cada elemento é separado por ":"
      $minutos = $quebraHora[0];
      $minutos = $minutos*60;
      $tot =$minutos+$quebraHora[1];

      $percentual = round(($tot / $total) * 100);

      $percentual_total .= "Tempo: " . $key . ", Percentual: " . $percentual . "<br>";
}

 echo $percentual_total;
```

---

---

### Porque seu script deu errado?

> Devemos ter sempre em mente que só podemos efetuar operações matemáticas para uma mesma grandeza com números que representem exatamente a mesma unidade de medida. Você estava querendo fazer uma operação matemática envolvendo números com duas unidades de medidas, hora e minutos. Poderia sim, se transformasse em horas decimais, exemplo, `(4,5hs/1,5hs)` resultado: `3 períodos de 1,5hs`

No código abaixo transformei o array em horas decimais `$array = array('4.75', '1.5', '0.75');` e o total de horas também `$total = '7.0';`

- horas decimais - exemplo: 4horas e 45minutos, em decimais, são 4 horas e 3 quartos de hora, ou seja, 4.75

Dessa forma poderemos fazer operações matemáticas como se pode ver a seguir:

```
$array = array('4.75', '1.5', '0.75');

$total = '7.0';

 foreach ($array as $tem => $key) {

      $percentual = round(($key / $total) * 100);

      $percentual_total .= "Tempo: " . $key . ", Percentual: " . $percentual . "\n";
}

 echo $percentual_total;
```

[**resultado no ideone**](https://ideone.com/iehyXW)

---

---

> Voltando as operações que você estava querendo fazer, temos que o PHP simplesmente ignorou a parte das horas após os dois pontos inclusive os dois pontos. Então `04:45` se transformou em `4` e `'07:00'` em `7`.
>   Resultado  `round((4 / 7) * 100);` é exatamente `57` [**veja no ideone**](https://ideone.com/iVCDZE)

Comment: Esta solução altera as premissas da dúvida. As entradas devem ser em formato de hora HH:MM e a saída deve ser o calculo percentual.

Comment: @DiegoMarques acho que você não entendeu a premissa da explicação complementar que atenta para o fato do autor estar fazendo uma operação matematica com unidades de medidas não apropriadas. A solução está estampada na primeira parte da resposta e que atende perfeitamente a pergunta do autor.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação amigo, o código atendeu perfeitamente. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria essa:

```
// Array com os horários
$array = array('04:45', '01:30', '00:45');

// Array que será armazenado as porcentagens
$porc = array();

// Total em mintuos
$total = 0;

// Varre o array dos horários e converte para inteiro
foreach ($array as $key => $time) {
    sscanf($time, "%d:%d", $hours, $minutes);
    $mins = $hours * 60 + $minutes;
    array_push($porc, $mins);
    $total += $mins;
}

// Converte os inteiros para porcentagem
$porc = array_map(function($value) use ($total) {
    return round(($value / $total) * 100, 2);
}, $porc);

// Exibe os valores
foreach ($array as $key => $time) {
    echo "Tempo: " . $time . ", Percentual: " . $porc[$key] . "%<br>";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, o código atendeu ao que eu precisava. Abraço.